# Need a 'text' parameter to parse duckling rasa x

Tags: rasa-x, named-entity-extraction, duckling

I am trying to run duckling locally. So with the help of this [article](https://medium.com/@adboio/using-duckling-to-extract-dates-and-times-in-your-rasa-chatbot-7687f4fde2e0) I installed stack, and then

cloned duckling code

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/duckling.git
```

download the zoneinfo and updated the reference in **exe/ExampleMain.hs**

```
  let defaultPath = "duckling/exe/zoneinfo/"
  let fallbackPath = "exe/zoneinfo/"
```

build using

```
stack build
```

then run using

```
stack exec duckling-example-exe
```

now if i hit **http://localhost:8000/parse** in the postman with request type POST and with following content

```
{
    "text": "tommorow",
    "locale": "de_DE",
    "tz": "Europe/Berlin",
    "dims": [
        "time"
    ],
    "reftime": 1616571265000
}
```

it shows `422 bad input`

```
Need a 'text' parameter to parse
```

and if i hit the same request again it shows `200 OK`

```
quack!
```

any help?

Comment: how can we add indian time zone ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to send the request as a JSON, however, the "http://localhost:8000/parse" endpoint expects the input to be sent as "form-encoded" data.

Refer to this image for a sample snapshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqdz4.png

Comment: how can we add indian time zone ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the source code of RASA open source. They are using `requests` python library to use duckling inside RASA for data parsing.

Here is the source code, [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/e341d1aa4b1aafb77f30c21eb13e5a9eb5fb3b2d/rasa/nlu/extractors/_duckling_entity_extractor.py#L61)

It will be so useful to know the correct format of text data.

Also, I will show you how to use duckling through a simple example:

1. Be sure that you compile and run the binary:

```sh
$ stack build
$ stack exec duckling-example-exe
```

2. Insdie pythod code environment or any IDE that support python run the following:

```py
import requests
t = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8000/parse', data={'text':'tomorrow at eight', 'locale':'en_GB'})
print(t.text)
```

The output is

```
[{"body":"tomorrow at eight","start":0,"value":{"values":[{"value":"2021-09-27T08:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour","type":"value"},{"value":"2021-09-27T20:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour","type":"value"}],"value":"2021-09-27T08:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour","type":"value"},"end":17,"dim":"time","latent":false}]
```